# .autocomplete is not a function MVC4

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**my model**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){<fieldset>
    <legend>Person Search</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        @*@ko.Html.Button("Search", "SearchPerson", "Person")*@
    </p>
```

}

**scripts in the view**

```
 <script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("PersonNameAutocomplete", "Person")', { minChars: 3 });
});
```

Error is TypeError: $("#Name").autocomplete is not a function

Comment: When you look at the source for the page in the browser is your url for autocomplete.js getting created properly?  Can you follow it to the script successfully?

Comment: Yes, autocomplete.js is successfully

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error and was put scripts in another area, so

```
 @section Scripts 
 {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
     <script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 }
```

Comment: go ahead and mark this as an answer if you've solved your own problem